# Find duplicate value Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of names, and if a user try to update one of them and is duplicate, I want to do something (error message) The problem is that is always duplicate. Pname will be changed on every keypress. I am not sure how to store the initial array and to compare with it.

```
<input
    v-model="Pname"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
/>

for(let element of this.customer_names){
    if(this.Pname == element.name){
       duplicateValue = +1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as:

```
if(this.customer_names.indexOf(this.Pname) != -1) {
  // there is a duplicate somewhere
}
```

Put that code in your change/key-up event listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use @blur like this:

```
<input
  v-model="Pname"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  @blur="findDuplicate"
>

function findDuplicate () {
  if(this.customer_names.indexOf(this.Pname) != -1) {
    // There is a duplicate
  }
}
```

So, by this when you click outside, after you are done with typing, it will run that findDuplicate function.

Comment: Ok, but the this.customer_name is changed, after I type something, and the new inserted value will be there, so always I got the message that the value is duplicate.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if it helps!!

Comment: Ok, but like I said , this.customer_names is changed on every new input. this.Pname is an element of this.customer_names.